# I'd rather you hadn't

Tags: sentence-construction, negation

1. I’d rather do something
2. I’d rather not do something
3. I’d rather **not have** done something
4. I’d rather you did something
5. I’d rather you did not do something
6. I’d rather you **had not** done something

When changing the sentence into the negative one, why the particle "not" comes before "have" in 3 and after "had" in example 6.
There is also a possibility that I have constructed the sentences in a wrong way.
Please, advise!

Comment: Great question, and I can give you a partial answer. The normal rule in English is that "not" comes after the last auxiliary verb. This rule explains all the sentences except #3. Also, the following sentence is correct: 3b. "*I'd rather **have not** done something.*" So the question is why it's allowable in this sentence to have "not" before "have". I have a feeling it's because "rather not" is an irregular idiom, but I'm not confident enough to make this a proper answer.

Answer (score 2):

The following four are all acceptable:

- "I’d rather you **not have** cheated that day."
- "I’d rather you **had not** cheated that day."
- "I’d rather **not have** gone to the party."
- "I’d rather **have not** gone to the party."

Some of these sentences *sound* more normal than others, but none of them are strictly breaking any widely accepted written rule. So the problem is not that we are being inconsistent in how we treat "you" and "I", it's just that your list didn't contain all possible versions of the sentences that are acceptable!

Answer (score 1):

> I’d rather **do** something.
> I’d rather **not do** something.
> I’d rather **not have done** something.

In these sentences, *do* and *have done* are bare infinitives. A bare infinitive is an infinitive without *to*. For example:

> *To-infinitive:* I decided **to travel** more.
> *Bare infinitive:* I should **travel** more.

*Have done* is a perfect infinitive. It refers to the past. For example:

> *To-infinitive:* He pretended **to have seen** this movie.
> *Bare infinitive:* I should **have called** her.

As you can see, modal verbs (*should* in these examples) typically require a bare infinitive.

To make an infinitive negative, you should put a *not* in front of it.

> *To-infinitive:* I decided **not to travel** more.
> *Bare infinitive:* I should **not travel** more.
>
> *To-infinitive:* He pretended **not to have seen** this movie.
> *Bare infinitive:* I should **not have called** her.

The *d* in *'d rather* is short for *would*, and *would* is a modal verb that requires a bare infinitive. Therefore, the *not* should go before that bare infinitive.

---

> I’d rather you **did** something.
> I’d rather you **did not do** something.
> I’d rather you **had not done** something.

Here, *you did something*, *you did not do something*, and *you had not done something* are clauses. They have a subject (*you*) and a verb (*do*). To make a verb negative, you should put an auxiliary verb in front of it and add a *not* after that auxiliary verb.

---

You could also take a look at [this useful article](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/would-rather-would-sooner).

Comment: athlonusm, thank you for your explanation! It took me some to time to absorb it, but now the pieces of the puzzle fall in place just right with this expalantion.